# Error when connect AWS MySQL with Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I am able to access AWS MySQL running on Kubernetes (required access keyId and secret key while setup & configuration).

#### Errors

When connecting with Spring Boot application to MySQL, I am getting errors:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Screenshot:
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix this java mysql exception: Communications link failure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262498/how-to-fix-this-java-mysql-exception-communications-link-failure)

Comment: Did you troubleshoot using [AWS MySQL docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html#USER_ConnectToInstance.JDBCDriverMySQL), especially the connection URL ?